# python - Common lists among lists in a list

Tags: python, list, coordinate

I need to be able to find the first common list (which is a list of coordinates in this case) between a variable amount of lists.

i.e. this list

```
>>> [[[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],[[3,4],[5,9],[8,3],[4,2]],[[3,4],[9,9]]]
```

should return

```
>>> [3,4]
```

If easier, I can work with a list of all common lists(coordinates) between the lists that contain the coordinates.

I can't use sets or dictionaries because lists are not hashable(i think?).

Comment: Is "common" meaning "contained in every list", or "non-unique in the lists"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct, `list` objects are not hashable because they are mutable.  `tuple` objects are hashable (provided that all their elements are hashable).  Since your innermost lists are all just integers, that provides a wonderful opportunity to work around the non-hashableness of lists:

```
>>> lists = [[[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],[[3,4],[5,9],[8,3],[4,2]],[[3,4],[9,9]]]
>>> sets = [set(tuple(x) for x in y) for y in lists]
>>> set.intersection(*sets)
set([(3, 4)])
```

Here I give you a set which contains tuples of the coordinates which are present in all the sublists.  To get a list of list like you started with:

```
[list(x) for x in set.intersection(*sets)]
```

does the trick.

To address the concern by @wim, if you really want a **reference** to the *first* element in the intersection (where `first` is defined by being first in `lists[0]`), the easiest way is probably like this:

```
#... Stuff as before
intersection = set.intersection(*sets)
reference_to_first = next( (x for x in lists[0] if tuple(x) in intersection), None )
```

This will return `None` if the intersection is empty.

Comment: -1  I don't think this guarantees to find the _first common_ duplicate

Comment: +1, because the question also reads "If easier, I can work with a list of all common lists(coordinates) between the lists that contain the coordinates."

Comment: @wim -- Fair enough.  I didn't see the *first* criteria.  Although, I'm not sure that's well defined either.  Consider `[[[1,2],[2,1]],[[2,1],[1,2]]]`.  What is first?

Comment: @wim -- If you really needed to, you could `sorted` the output based on their position in one of the original lists (arbitrarily chosen?).  I still think that might be more efficient than a solution based on `list.__contains__`

Comment: As I understood it `[1,2]` would be first in that case, but maybe I'm making assumptions.  I also took the question to mean that a reference on the duplicate list is needed, whereas your method would generate a copy with no way to modify the actual duplicate..

Comment: @wim -- I believe I have addressed both of your concerns with 1 line of code (and better than O(N) complexity on average) ;-).

Comment: Good, but I think you meant `intersection = set.intersection(*sets)` instead of `intersection = set.intersection(sets)`.  Also I think yours will return the reference to the _first (original) which has a duplicate_, rather than a reference to the first duplicate.  That's probably not important for whatever practical use case, but worth mentioning ..

Comment: @wim -- Correct you are!  Thanks for the read-behind (and for pushing me to make a better answer)

Comment: Nice and simple. I managed in getting the individual one I needed since I never mentioned that the lists I had were sorted. Thanks!

Comment: @PabloMelana-Dayton -- Glad to help.  It was a fun problem that I enjoyed creating a somewhat clever solution for (It was especially fun with the constraints that wim kept putting on :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the first child list that is common amongst all parent lists, the following will work.

```
def first_common(lst):
    first = lst[0]
    rest = lst[1:]
    for x in first:
        if all(x in r for r in rest):
            return x
```

Comment: This is unfortunately algorithmically slow: first creating sets (like in mglison's answer) gives much faster tests than the `x in r` tests done for each list `r` and for each element `x`. However, this has the advantage of returning the first element `x` found in `first`, so this may be good enough, depending on the needs: +1. In some applications, it may be more efficient to convert the elements in `rest` into tuples, like in mgilson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with recursive function. :)

This gets first duplicated element.

```
def get_duplicated_element(array):
    global result, checked_elements
    checked_elements = []
    result = -1
    def array_recursive_check(array):
        global result, checked_elements
        if result != -1: return
        for i in array:
            if type(i) == list:
                if i in checked_elements:
                    result = i
                    return
                checked_elements.append(i)
                array_recursive_check(i)
    array_recursive_check(array)
    return result

get_duplicated_element([[[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],[[3,4],[5,9],[8,3],[4,2]],[[3,4],[9,9]]])
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [[[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],[[3,4],[5,9],[8,3],[4,2]],[[3,4],[9,9]]]
>>> lcombined =  sum(l, [])
>>> [k[0] for k in [(i,lcombined.count(i)) for i in lcombined] if k[1] > 1][0]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: This does not work: only elements found in *all* the lists should be returned, not elements found in more than one list.